# Unable to create a bot in Azure due to Microsoft.Web Resource Provider

Tags: azure, bots

I have a free Azure account, and I am trying to create a BOT.  I am following along with the documentation provided by Microsoft, but I keep getting the same error.  The Error Message says "Resource provider 'Microsoft.Web' not registered for this subscription."  I can go to my Azure Resource Providers page and see that the Microsoft.Web resource is shown ad Registering and not Registered.  It has been this way for over a day now, and I am not sure what I need to do to get it to the Registered status.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.  It took about 4 days for the Microsoft.Web resource to move from Registering to Registered.  My advice for others having this problem is to just be patient for a few days and it should become resolved.